# Hibernate : I don't want to fetch association fields with Lazy or Eager Loading

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have 4 classes : Room, Message, User, RoomUser.

Here the association parts of these classes :

**Room**

```
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="messageRoom")
    @Where(clause = "messages_enabled = true")
    protected Set<Message> messages;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="room")
    protected Set<RoomUser> users;
```

**Message**

```
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "messages_room")
    private Room messageRoom;
```

**User**

```
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="user")
    private Set<RoomUser> rooms;
```

**RoomUser**

```
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="rooms_id")
    private Room room; // int
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="users_id")
    private User user; // long
```

What I want is to **NOT load** *messages* and *users* in the Room entity (even if it's EAGER or LAZY) when I request my database within CrudRepository.
So I put FetchType.LAZY thinking it will not load these fields if I don't call getters and setters.
BUT, datas are loaded anyway !!

Here my controller, service and repository :

**Controller**

```
    @GetMapping(path = {"/get/{id}"}, produces="application/json")
    public void findComplete(@PathVariable int id) {
        Room room = this.roomService.findRoomById(id);
        //System.out.println(room.toString());
    }
```

**Service**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Room findRoomById(int id) {
        return this.roomRepository.findById(id);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Integer> {

    public Set<Room> findByName(String name);

    public Room findById(int id);
}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: How do you know they were loaded? Also, `@OneToMany` is lazy by default, whereas `@ManyToOne` is eager by default.

Comment: @Kayaman I uncomment the "System.out.println(room.toString());" in the controller and the console prints 2 users and 2 messages with all their fields (as in the database). But I never call getters nor setters in my code during the process.. And ManyToOne in Message entity is also LAZY so it should not be loaded

Comment: But your `toString()` initializes those collections. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to print them out. Enable the SQL output in Hibernate, and you can see exactly what calls are made to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Try with 
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)